# The difference between "irony" and "paradox"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage

What is the exact difference between irony and a paradox? I've tried looking this up and I seem to have a vague idea about it, but it'd be great if someone could illustrate with an example or two.

An example I encountered: *"John lacks a sense of humor. Ironically, he was born on the 1st of April."*

Comment: Welcome to ELU.SE. Please note that it makes answering easier if you state explicitly what you found in your research and why it doesn't tell you what you need to know. That way, answers won't repeat what wasn't helpful and can concentrate on explaining. As the (current) answer indicates, Wikipedia can often be a useful starting point.

Answer (score 5):

A paradox is something that appears to **contradict** itself, ie to generate or propose a logically impossible situation.

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/paradox

Irony actually has several different forms, but for example refers to a statement that **deliberately means something different** to what it appears to mean, or a situation in which **one party is ignorant of the true meaning** or true situation.  There are several different kinds of irony, as I said, so it's hard to encapsulate in a single sentence.

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/irony

Most ironic statements are not paradoxes, and most paradoxes are not ironic.  There will be some crossover, ie you could find some paradoxes which are ironic, but they are logically quite different.

If you would like to edit your question with an example of a specific phrase which you find confusing then I analyse which category it fits into.

EDIT:  An example of irony: "John lacks a sense of humor. Ironically, he was born on the 1st of April."

First of all, there's nothing **paradoxical** about this: there's no logical reason why having no sense of humour would prevent someone being born on a particular day, or vice versa.

The referred-to irony is an example (I think) of what that wiktionary page calls "informal or proscribed irony": *"Contradiction between circumstances and expectations; condition contrary to what might be expected."*

April the first is known as "april fools day" in some countries, and a tradition is to try to trick one another with humourous fiction which is portrayed as being serious - for example, joke newspaper articles.  (These are themselves ironic - I think they are examples of *Socratic irony*)

So, by coincidence, this person without humour was born on a day which traditionally contains a lot of humour, and thus there is a sort of contradiction due to this coincidence, hence the irony.

Obviously, a logical response to the claim that this is ironic could be to say "It's not really ironic, because there's no reason that being born on the 1st of april should make someone more humourous", and this would obviously be correct.  The irony is really just about the coincidence, or colocation, of an extra-humourous thing (the day) with an unhumourous thing (the person).

Comment: Thank you @Max. Well, I came across this usage of irony - "John lacks a sense of humor. Ironically, he was born on the 1st of April." I was wondering if this is correct. I did read up on the classic definitions but wasn't sure how to classify them properly.

Comment: I've edited your question to include this.

Answer (score 1):

George Orwell's novel, *1984*, contained the doublethink slogans: [*WAR IS PEACE*](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=paradox+%22war+is+peace%22), *FREEDOM IS SLAVERY*. If there is war, how can there be peace? Someone who is a slave cannot be free. These are good examples of paradoxes.

The one man Winston trusted and  considered a friend, was in reality his enemy, and responsible for Winston's arrest and subsequent torture. This is an example of *bitter irony*.

> **[tragic/bitter/cruel irony](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/irony)**
>
> a strange, funny, or sad situation in which things happen in the opposite way to what you would expect
> *By a cruel irony, General Franklin was killed at the very moment of his army’s great victory.*